# Intercept keyup event before an already bound listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using a third-party library, which binds the `keyup` event using the `addEventListener` method, as in:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', handler);
```

I would like to prevent this listener from firing when a condition is met, like:

```
$(document).on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (condition) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        // ...
    }
});
```

However, because of the nature of the solution I'm writing, it's impossible for me to bind my handler before the one bound by the external library - the other listener fires up before mine, so I can't actually prevent anything like that.

Is there a way to somehow move my listener before the third-party one? Or somehow hijack the `keyup` in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

And if you to use the keydown event?

This event occurs before of keyup.

Like this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function (e) {

});
```

If this is not the question, let's try something else.
:)

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be the `keyup` event. Of course my listener would fire as the first one, but I would still have no way of preventing the third party `keyup` listener from firing.